# Send Email via Gmail from Command Prompt

Tags: windows, email, gmail, command-line

I've got some backup jobs running weekly and would like to have the log files sent to me automatically via email so I don't have to manually check them.

On a Windows system, is there a tool that I can use that will allow me to send an email via Gmail SMTP from a command prompt?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gmail can be used for sending mail by any mail program and from any network.

Some command-line mail products for Windows are:

[SendEmail](http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/)
[mailsend](http://www.muquit.com/muquit/software/mailsend/mailsend.html)
(I have no first-hand experience with these products.)

See also this article : [How to use Gmail as your SMTP server](http://lifehacker.com/111166/how-to-use-gmail-as-your-smtp-server).

Comment: If it's from a "remote server" you need to enable some security measures too, see the various answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail/49429541#49429541

Answer (score 2):

[Blat](http://www.blat.net/):

> **What is Blat?**
>   Blat is a Win32 command line utility that sends eMail using SMTP or post to usenet using NNTP.

Answer (score 2):

HowToGeek demonstrates a Windows PowerShell script that works very well at [How To Send Email From the Command Line in Windows Without Extra Software](http://www.howtogeek.com/120011/stupid-geek-tricks-how-to-send-email-from-the-command-line-in-windows-without-extra-software/)

Here is the method:
First you're defining the variables:

> $EmailFrom = “yourMail@gmail.com”
>   $EmailTo = “theRecipient'sAddress@someServer.com”
>   $Subject = “your subject”
>   $Body = “some text”
>   $SMTPServer = “smtp.gmail.com”
>   $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
>   $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
>   $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential(“yourGmailUsername”, “password”);

Then, you're using this command to send the mail:

> $SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)

You'll need a valid Gmail account in order to authenticate as a Gmail user.

Answer (score 1):

Currently in powershell we can use `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet without using .NET:

```
$Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential(“yourGmailUsername”, “password”);
Send-MailMessage -From 'enterYourEmailHere ' -To 'enterRecipientMailHere' -Subject 'Email subject' -Body 'EnterBodyHere as HTML'  -Attachment 'Attachment path here' -SmtpServer 'smtp.gmail.com' -Port 587 -UseSSL -BodyAsHTML -Credential $Credentials
```

[Send-MailMessage Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following java program to send email through command line
https://ps06756.wordpress.com/2017/08/17/how-to-send-email-through-gmail-programmatically/